# Calculator shows number with operator on one edittext - Android

Tags: android, calculator

So I have a simple calculator, it works but it doesn't show the full equation (like numbers with operators) on the edittext. What I want to do now is to show the full equation in the edittext. For example, I want to show 8 + 8 , then when I click the = sign, that's when the results change to 16. I just want to show the whole equation. How can I do that with my code? Can someone help me.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public String str ="";
 Character op = 'q';
 int i,num,numtemp;
    EditText showResult;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

        showResult = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.result_id);


    }
      public void btn1Clicked(View v){
       insert(1);

      }

 public void btn2Clicked(View v){
       insert(2);

      }
      public void btn3Clicked(View v){
       insert(3);

      }
      public void btn4Clicked(View v){
       insert(4);

      }
      public void btn5Clicked(View v){
       insert(5);

      }
      public void btn6Clicked(View v){
       insert(6);
      }
      public void btn7Clicked(View v){
       insert(7);

      }
      public void btn8Clicked(View v){
       insert(8);

      }
      public void btn9Clicked(View v){
       insert(9);

      }

      public void btn0Clicked(View v){
           insert(0);

          }


      public void btnplusClicked(View v){
       perform();
       op = '+';

      }

 public void btnminusClicked(View v){
    perform();
         op = '-';

      }
      public void btndivideClicked(View v){
       perform();
       op = '/';

      }
      public void btnmultiClicked(View v){
       perform();
       op = '*';

      }
      public void btnequalClicked(View v){
       calculate();

      }

 public void btnclearClicked(View v){
       reset();
      }

 private void reset() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   str ="";
   op ='q';
   num = 0;
   numtemp = 0;
   showResult.setText("");
 }
 private void insert(int j) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       str = str+Integer.toString(j);
       num = Integer.valueOf(str).intValue();
       showResult.setText(str);


   }
      private void perform() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    str = "";
    numtemp = num;
   }
      private void calculate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(op == '+')
     num = numtemp+num;
    else if(op == '-')
     num = numtemp-num;
    else if(op == '/')
     num = numtemp/num;
    else if(op == '*')
     num = numtemp*num;
    showResult.setText(""+num);
   }

}
```

Comment: @MikeM. but how can I do that with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way, keeping as much of your existing current code as possible, is to just create a second string to hold the text to be displayed. So your insert() would become:

```
 private void insert(int j) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    str = str+Integer.toString(j);
    num = Integer.valueOf(str).intValue();
    displayStr += Integer.toString(j);   // Added
    showResult.setText(displayStr);
}
```

Each of your operation methods would need to append to the displayStr. So the one for the minus key would become:

```
public void btnminusClicked(View v){
    perform();
    op = '-';
    displayStr += "-";                   // Added     
}
```

And your reset would need an added line to empty-out the display string:

```
    displayStr = "";                     // Added
```

There may be a couple more tweaks, but that should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: I got null before the number I input.

Comment: Yeah, that's one of the tweaks that I was leaving room for. You'll have to create and initialize the display string at the top: public String displayStr = "";

Comment: Thanks! It's working now. But why the operator shows up only when I input the second number?

Comment: Because the showResult is only being updated when a number is entered. You'll need to update it with showResult.setText(displayStr) in each operation method. Since you're now duplicating more than one line of code in those methods, you might want to abstract out the duplicated lines into a separate method.

Comment: wow thank you so much it's working perfectly now. But I have a new challenge regarding the calculator, can you help me with this? here's the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22704849/simple-calculator-with-multiple-operations-android

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 private void calculate() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if(op == '+')
 num = numtemp+num;
else if(op == '-')
 num = numtemp-num;
else if(op == '/')
 num = numtemp/num;
else if(op == '*')
 num = numtemp*num;
showResult.setText(""+numtemp+op+num);   //there is a change
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Change your calulate function as below:

```
private void calculate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          String first=String.valueOf(numtemp);
          String second=String.valueOf(num);
    if(op == '+')
     num = numtemp+num;
    else if(op == '-')
     num = numtemp-num;
    else if(op == '/')
     num = numtemp/num;
    else if(op == '*')
     num = numtemp*num;

    showResult.setText(first+op+second+"="+num);
   }
```

Comment: Thanks it works but its not what I want to do, I want to show the equation while inputting the numbers and operator and not after clicking the = sign. We're getting there, please help.