# Simple Calculator with multiple operations - Android

Tags: android, calculator, operations

I have created a simple calculator that calculates two inputs (ex. 2 + 2 = 4). What I want to do now is to make the app to calculate multiple operations like (ex. 2 + 2 * 4 - 1 = 15). Can someone help me with my code? Here is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public String str ="";

 Character op = 'q';
 int i,num,numtemp;
    EditText showResult;
    String displayStr = "";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

        showResult = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.result_id);


    }
      public void btn1Clicked(View v){
       insert(1);

      }

 public void btn2Clicked(View v){
       insert(2);

      }
      public void btn3Clicked(View v){
       insert(3);

      }
      public void btn4Clicked(View v){
       insert(4);

      }
      public void btn5Clicked(View v){
       insert(5);

      }
      public void btn6Clicked(View v){
       insert(6);
      }
      public void btn7Clicked(View v){
       insert(7);

      }
      public void btn8Clicked(View v){
       insert(8);

      }
      public void btn9Clicked(View v){
       insert(9);

      }

      public void btn0Clicked(View v){
           insert(0);

          }


      public void btnplusClicked(View v){
       perform();
       op = '+';
       displayStr += "+";
      }

 public void btnminusClicked(View v){
     perform();
        op = '-';
        displayStr += "-";    

      }
      public void btndivideClicked(View v){
       perform();
       op = '/';
       displayStr += "/";
      }
      public void btnmultiClicked(View v){
       perform();
       op = '*';
       displayStr += "*";
      }
      public void btnequalClicked(View v){
       calculate();

      }

 public void btnclearClicked(View v){
       reset();
      }
      private void reset() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   str ="";
   op ='q';
   num = 0;
   numtemp = 0;
   displayStr = "";
   showResult.setText("");
 }
 private void insert(int j) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       str = str+Integer.toString(j);
       num = Integer.valueOf(str).intValue();

       displayStr += Integer.toString(j); 
       showResult.setText(displayStr);

   }
      private void perform() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    str = "";
    numtemp = num;
   }
      private void calculate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String first=String.valueOf(numtemp);
     String second=String.valueOf(num);

          if(op == '+')
     num = numtemp+num;
    else if(op == '-')
     num = numtemp-num;
    else if(op == '/')
     num = numtemp/num;
    else if(op == '*')
     num = numtemp*num;
showResult.setText(first+op+second+"="+num);
   }

}
```

Comment: Its quite simple, please Google on priorities of arithematic operation i mean like u said for 2 + 2 * 4 - 1 so check out which operation is performed on priority and rest you can program using your logic. :) please look @ http://www.mathsisfun.com/operation-order-bodmas.html

1. Brackets first (starting with the innermost)
2. exponentials or powers next
3. multiplications and divisions next
4. additions and subtractions last
5. if an expression involves three or mo
re operations at the same level of
priority, those operations are done from left to right.

Comment: Please visit https://github.com/ajitjangra/SimpleCalculator

Answer (score 2):

Use some stack operations.
May be the below links will helpful to you.

http://innovativenetsolutions.com/2013/01/calculator-app/
http://www.androiddom.com/2011/04/creating-android-calculator-tutorial.html

Comment: Link only answers are bad. They external pages could go offline and the link is useless. Please put the main aspects of that links to your answer and put a reference to that pages.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **stack operations** for performing this kind of arithmetic evaluations programatically.
Please check this link [**Arithmetic Operations using Stack**](http://www.smccd.net/accounts/hasson/C++2Notes/ArithmeticParsing.html)  for the algorithm you need to write.